# Show that $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}$ is derivable

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I need some clue on the following:

Define $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}$

Find the convergence domain and show that f is derivable there.

I'm pretty sure it converges for $x > 1$

How do I show that it's derivable there?

Thanks :)

Comment: Use the uniform convergence plus the fact that $\log n = o(n^{\epsilon})$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Two possibilities : show that $\lim_{h \to 0} |\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - (\sum_n(-\ln n) n^{-x})|  = 0$, or use the uniform convergence of $g(x) = \sum_n(-\ln n) n^{-x})$ for showing that $\int_a^x g(t)dt = f(x)-f(a)$

Comment: What do you think the derivative should be?  Show that as $h\to0$, $|g(x)-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h|\to0$.

Comment: For showing $|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - (\sum_n(-\ln n) n^{-x})|  \to 0$ Apply $\left|\frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h}-u'(x)\right| = \left|\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h} (u'(t)-u'(x))dt\right|$ $=\left|\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}\int_x^t u''(s)dsdt\right|$ $ < |h|\sup_{|y| < |h|} |u''(x+y)| $ to $u(x) = n^{-x}$ and use that $\sum_n |n^{|h|-x} \ln^2n|$ converges (when $h$ is small enough)

Comment: How can I show that $g_n(x)$ uniformly converges? Tried M test with no success.

Comment: $\sum_n n^{-x} (\ln n)^k$  converges uniformly on $x \ge a > 1$ because it converges absolutely and each term is decreasing in $x$

Comment: I should prove that if I want to use that statement. Is it correct to use Raabe–Duhamel's test for this?